# XSLT remove() function

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

In XSLT, there is a `remove()` function for sequences. Given a sequence and a position, it returns the sequence minus the item at the given position.

The question is: **How do I employ this function in an actual XSLT file?**

The only place I've found mention of an example that isn't just a regurgitation of the function spec completely devoid of context is here: http://books.google.com/books?id=W6SpffnfEPoC&pg=PA776&lpg=PA776&dq=xslt+%22remove+function%22&source=bl&ots=DQQrnXF_nB&sig=nrJtpEvYjBaZU0K8iAtdPTGUIbI&hl=en&sa=X&ei=QOq8T7aPDOyI6AHh-JBP&ved=0CEQQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=xslt%20%22remove%20function%22&f=false

Unfortunately, the stylesheet examples are on pages 777 and 778, which are, of course, not included. And I don't own that book.

So, does anyone have an example of using the `remove()` XSLT function in an actual stylesheet?

**Edit:** Let's provide a slightly more concrete example, shall we?

I have a sequence in an XSLT. This sequence is comprised of all of the lines from a text file.

```
<xsl:variable name="lines" select="tokenize(unparsed-text($filePath), '\r?\n')" />
```

Every one of these lines is a record...except for one, which gives me the record count. So I have the following code for finding that line:

```
<xsl:variable name="recordCount">
  <xsl:for-each select="$lines[position()]">
    <xsl:variable name="i" select="position()" />
    <xsl:analyze-string select="$lines[$i]" regex="RECORD COUNT = \d+">
      <xsl:matching-substring>
        <xsl:value-of select="replace($lines[$i], '[^0-9]', '')" />
      </xsl:matching-substring>
    </xsl:analyze-string>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
```

I do the above before I start looping through the lines to get all the actual records, so my goal here is to remove the "RECORD COUNT" line from the `$lines` sequence when I find it. That way when I'm looping through grabbing records I don't have to do a check every time asking "Is this actually not a record, but in fact the RECORD COUNT line? You know, that thing I looked for and found already?"

**Edit (2):** Based on Martin Honnen's answer(s), my final XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
  <!-- I want to produce an XML document. -->
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <!-- Path to input text file. -->
  <xsl:param name="filePath" select="TestFile.txt" />

  <!-- Regex in replace() removes leading and trailing blank space. -->
  <xsl:variable name="text" select="replace(unparsed-text($filePath), '(^[\r\n]*\s*[\r\n]+)|([\r\n]+\s*[\r\n]*$)', '')" />

  <!-- Regex in tokenize() sets the delimiter to be any blank space between record lines. -->
  <!-- This effectively removes any blank lines. -->
  <xsl:variable name="lines" select="tokenize($text, '[\r\n]+\s*[\r\n]*')" />

  <!-- This finds the "RECORD COUNT = ?" line. -->
  <xsl:variable name="recordCountIndex"
    select="for $pos in 1 to count($lines) return $pos[matches($lines[$pos], 'RECORD COUNT = \d+')]" />

  <!-- Regex in replace() strips everything that's not a number, leaving only the numeric count. -->
  <!-- Example: "RECORD COUNT = 25" -> "25" -->
  <xsl:variable name="recordCount" select="replace($lines[$recordCountIndex], '[^0-9]', '')" />

  <xsl:template name="main">
    <root>
      <recordCount>
        <!-- The record count value being inserted. -->
        <xsl:value-of select="$recordCount" />
      </recordCount>
      <records>
        <!-- Iterate over the $lines minus the line containing the record count. -->
        <xsl:for-each select="remove($lines, $recordCountIndex)">
          <!-- Items in each record, split by blank space. -->
          <!-- Example: "a b c" -> "[a, b, c]" -->
          <xsl:variable name="record" select="tokenize(., ' ')[position()]" />
          <record>
            <aThing>
              <xsl:value-of select="$record[1]" />
            </aThing>
            <aDifferentThing>
              <xsl:value-of select="$record[2]" />
            </aDifferentThing>
            <someStuff>
              <xsl:value-of select="$record[3]" />
            </someStuff>
          </record>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </records>
    </root>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well

```
<xsl:variable name="seq1" select="1, 2, 3, 4"/>
<xsl:variable name="seq2" select="remove($seq1, 2)"/>
```

makes the value of the variable `seq2` a sequence of three number values 1, 3, 4.

[edit]

Here is an example based on your edited problem description:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
  version="2.0">

  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:param name="filePath" select="'test2012052301.txt'"/>

  <xsl:variable name="lines" select="tokenize(unparsed-text($filePath), '\r?\n')" />

  <xsl:variable name="index" as="xs:integer"
    select="for $pos in 1 to count($lines) return $pos[matches($lines[$pos], 'RECORD COUNT = [0-9]+')]"/>

  <xsl:variable name="recordCount" as="xs:integer"
    select="xs:integer(replace($lines[$index], '[^0-9]', ''))"/>

  <xsl:template name="main">
    <xsl:value-of select="remove($lines, $index)" separator="&#10;"/>
    <xsl:text>count is: </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="$recordCount"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With the text file being for instance

```
foo
bar
RECORD COUNT = 3
baz
```

the stylesheet outputs

```
foo
bar
baz
count is: 3
```

[edit2]
I think you can shorten the section

```
  <records>
    <!-- The $lines sequence trimmed down to only consist of valid records. -->
    <!-- (I have found no way around having this intermediate variable.) -->
    <xsl:variable name="records" select="remove($lines, $recordCountIndex)" />
    <xsl:for-each select="$records[position()]">
      <!-- Variable for iteration. Perhaps there's a more elegant way to do this. -->
      <xsl:variable name="i" select="position()" />
      <!-- Items in each record, split by blank space. -->
      <!-- Example: "a b c" -> "[a, b, c]" -->
      <xsl:variable name="recordItems" select="tokenize($records[$i], ' ')" />
      <record>
        <item1>
          <xsl:value-of select="$recordItems[1]" />
        </item1>
        <item2>
          <xsl:value-of select="$recordItems[2]" />
        </item2>
        <item3>
          <xsl:value-of select="$recordItems[3]" />
        </item3>
      </record>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </records>
```

of your stylesheet to

```
  <records>
    <xsl:for-each select="remove($lines, $recordCountIndex)">
      <record>
        <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(., ' ')[position() lt 4]">
          <xsl:element name="item{position()}">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
          </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </record>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </records>
```

Actually the predicate `position() lt 4` is only needed if a line can contain more than three tokens.

And as a note, I have now seen a construct like `for-each select="$records[position()]` two times in your post, that predicate with `[position()]` is complete useless, you can simply use `for-each select="$records"`.

Comment: So I have to make an intermediate variable? In your example, is there any way to over-write seq1 with the result of the remove() call, instead of having to create a seq2 variable?

Comment: You don't have to use variables at all but as your post does not show any input data I had to make up some data and the shortest complete sample seemed to be using a variable. As for overwriting variables, that is not possible in a declarative language like XSLT, whether you use that particular function or not. If you want an example not using a variable to store the result of the function then use e.g. `<xsl:value-of select="remove($seq1, 2)" separator=", "/>` to output the result of calling that function on a sequence.

Comment: Added a bit of an example to hopefully explain my conundrum a little more clearly.

Comment: My latest edit tries to show how to simplify your code and also shows using the remove function. I simply output the sequence obtained, of course you could `for-each` over it if wanted/needed.

Comment: My latest edit shows my eventual XSLT. Unless you (or anyone else) knows a way around having that intermediate "records" variable to store the sequence returned from the remove() call or has a more elegant way to do the iterator in the next few days, I'm going to accept your answer when I come back from the holiday weekend.

Comment: I am used to imperative (procedural) languages, so I ended up trying to warp XSLT scripting to what I'm used to; explicit iterator variables, variables changing state, etc. These XSLT scripts kind of remind me of Lisp for some reason (which I am quite rusty in). In any case, your optimizations (can you call it optimization when you're simply replacing something I did stupidly?) are working, and I updated my question with a final version of the XSLT. I also changed the <itemX> tags to indicate that I meant them to be discrete data types within each record.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to work out exactly where your confusion lies.

Firstly, removing an item from a sequence will never remove a node from a tree. (I've fought against the way the spec talks about sequences "containing nodes"; I think it's better to think of them as containing references to nodes. So you're removing a reference to a node, which doesn't affect the node itself in any way.)

Secondly, you seem to be thinking of variables as they are sometimes described in procedural languages, as named boxes containing values, which can contain different values at different times. Don't think of XSLT and XQuery variables that way: think of them as named values. "Over-writing" just isn't a meaningful operation.

Finally, use-cases. The most common way I use remove is to get the tail of a sequence: `remove($seq, 1)`. You can also write that as `subsequence($seq, 2)` or as `$seq[position() gt 1]`, but `remove()` is fewer keystrokes. To be honest, I'm having trouble thinking of a real life example where I have used `remove()` any other way, and I can't think of one.

Which leads me to an observation about your question. Asking "how to I use this feature" is a pretty strange sort of question. What we expect people to ask is "how do I solve this problem". Sometimes, when people ask how to use a feature, they are struggling to solve a particular problem, but they aren't telling us what the problem is. It would help if you told us: there's a good chance that `remove()` isn't part of the solution.